# Alternative to get_posts() due to multithreading cache crash

Tags: get-posts, threading

I am using **pthreads** to creat multiple threads. Each of those threads at one point tries to use `get_posts()` as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'any'
);

$posts_list = get_posts($args);
```

However I end up with the following crash:

```
HP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\dev\wordpress\wp-includes\cache.php on line 123
```

**PLEASE NOTE** when I make the same `get_posts()` call in a code section that is not threaded, I do not have the crash.

Now, my question, how to call `get_posts()` from within a **pthread** thread? And if I cannot do that, what is the alternative?

Thanks.

---

### Update

Here is sample code

```
class My_Thread extends Thread {

    public function run() {

        /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'any'
        );

        $posts_list = get_posts($args); // <------ This is causing the crash
    }
}

// Create a array
$threads = array();

//Iniciate Miltiple Thread
foreach ( range("A", "C") as $i ) {
    $threads[] = new My_Thread($i);
}

// Start The Threads
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    $thread->start();
}
```

Comment: that is not a crash it is an error..... you should fix your code so there will not be an error. In any case php libraries are not always multitasking safe so the problem might be with something totally different.

Comment: To add, if there is code that needs to be protected for "same time" execution than you need to use mutexes but that is way out off scope here.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Thanks for your input. However, it seems like you missed the point where I state that "*when I make the same `get_posts()` call in a code section that is not threaded, I do not have the crash*"; so it is not a problem with my `get_posts($args)` call.  Moreover, there isn't code that needs to be protected at this point, I am just reading from the WordPress DB via `get_posts($args)`.

Comment: `WP_Object_Cache` probably exists in a different thread than the `WP_Query` object(s) in your `My_Thread` instances. Maybe you have to pass it explicitly to each `My_Thread` instance and globalize it there? Not sure, I haven't worked with pthreads yet.

Comment: @Greeso, if you don't understand multitasking than you should not even start using pthread. PHP is not thread safe and wordpress is not thread safe. If you want to use pthreads you need to work around those limitations, pretending they do not exist will not do you any good.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - What's wrong with you? Why are you so negative and so aggressive? Why do you assume I don't understand multitasking and suggest that I should not use pthreads? Even if you are correct, aren't we supposed to try what we don't understand to expand our knowledge and limits? And isn't this site about asking questions if you do not know how you do a certain thing? I am not pretending anything. I ecountered an error, I realized it is due to using pthreads, and I am asking for a solution, either a setup or a a programming workaround. I was hoping for a constructive answer from yourself.

Comment: @toscho - Thanks. Good idea. However it may make things too complex. I like simpler solutions. I will try your suggestion. I will also try to redesign my approach to solving the problem to overcome the multithreading part.

Comment: @Greeson, so again, wordpress is not designed to be multithread safe, not all part of PHP are, therefor complaining that using threads with wordpress produce errors is both old news and out of scope here, because multithreading is extremely hard and solving the errors you see is pointless as what is going to kill you are the errors that you will see only with real life traffic. In essence, in the context of wordpress multithreading is done by letting the web server create a new thread by issuing a new request and there is no need to use pthreas.

Comment: If you want to experiment with pthreads then the right place to ask questions about it is SO. here it is pointless to ask it as there are probably no more then 1 person that ever used it in a wordpress enviroment (my guess is actually zero)

Comment: Until we really **know** that WordPress isn't the reason to break this code, it is on topic.

Comment: I'm with toscho. This is still plausibly WordPress, though we may need more information from the OP to work things out.

Comment: I just like to update. It turned out that any DB access via a thread is causing an error (I tried using `$wpdb` directly and got a crash). However, I am able to multithread non-db related actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are so many upvotes to the question, although the issues of multithreading are just too broad for a format of an answer, I will try to explain why you should not use wordpress API in a multithreaded way....

TL;DR - PHP is not assumed to be multithreading ready, the problem is not PHP itself but mainly the libraries it uses. This is why it is recommended **not to use** the multithreaded execution mode in apache although in theory it should be somewhat faster. To add to the problem of underlying layer not being multithread ready, wordpress core violates the most basic requirement of multithread- no free access to globals.

What is the problem with globals in multithreaded enviroment? lets assume we have the naive looking code

```
function inc() {
  global $g;

  $g++;
}
```

While it is just a one liner, it is not an atomic operation for the CPU, and it take several machine level instruction to actoally execute it. Some thing like

```
move $g to register D
increment register D
move register D to $g
```

Now lets assume we have two threads A B that call `inc()` at the "same time" (obviously with only one CPU there is no such thing as same time), and that the initial value of $g is 0, what would be the value of $g after both threads finished? It will depend on how the OS handles multithreading, when does it switch between threads. In "older" style OSes it was the job of the thread to declare by calling an API that control can be taken from it, but that leads to many problems with bad behaving processes locking down the system therefor in "modern" OS the OS takes control when ever it feels like it. In real life the result of the code will be that $g will have a value of 2, but there is also the following possibility

In the context of A

```
move $g to register D
// value of D is 0
// OS stores the content of registers and switches to thread B
// B increments $g to 1 and finishes working
// OS restores content of registers to the context of thread A
// Value of register D is now 0
increment register D
move register D to $g
```

End result is that $g has the value of 1.

Obviously globals are not the only problem and handling inputs and outputs is also a core for mutithreading problems.

In proper multithreading code you use lock/mutex/semaphore/pipe/socket.... to serialize access to such global resources to make sure there will be a predictable result to the operation.
Wordpress do not do that.

Hell, wordpress is not even multi process safe. Most of the time it gets away with it because the DB schema is built in a way which in real life usage prevents the need to modify the same data from different processes (different posts has different rows and do not share data), but look at the sidebar/widgets code and try to imagine what will happen if two admins would try to add a different widget at exactly the same time. Since this will require the manipulation of one specific option the end result can be either both widgets added or only one of them.

Back to multithrading. In unix, unlike windows, the additional cost of spawning a process instead of thread is negligible, therefor using `wp_remote_get` with some special url to invoke additional "thread" is a very legitimate thing to do and avoid almost all the pitfalls associated with multithreading.

Comment: This is well explained. Thanks.  I also just found out that support for **pthreads** to work with **apache** is being removed. In order to make **pthreads** work, it should be within a **CLI** evironment. For me, I need **pthreads**, but I wil postpone this solution till after the release (i.e., an enhancement).  Also, I will need to setup WordPress as a CLI envornment (details here http://wp-cli.org/ ); doing so will allow me to work a pthreads/WordPress environment from CLI, alllowing me to do the heavy work at the backend without apache. Thaks again.

Comment: Just to add, I will restrict pthreads to deal with non-db related issues. And as per your suggestion, use mutex for db writes.

Comment: @Greeso, linux was designed to using multiple processes to handle concurrent execution needs, spawning a new process is really safer and as fast as using pthreads..